# How can I set the components of an fprint call to equal to a char variable in C?

Tags: c

I have a line in my code:

```
fprintf(f, "Timestamp, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s ", 
  channels[1].title, 
  channels[2].title, 
  channels[3].title, 
  channels[4].title, 
  channels[5].title, 
  channels[6].title, 
  channels[7].title);
```

I'd like for the line that it ends up printing to be set equal to a variable to use later in my program. I believe this is relatively simple to do but I am very knew to programming.

Comment: you should know that what you are trying to do is in fact one of the most difficult and annoying things to do with C, and far away from "relatively simple" =)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin What's difficult about it? Getting storage duration and/or scope right, or using `sprintf`/`snprintf` correctly? That word, 'difficult'... I do not think it means what you think it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to declare the variable somewhere. The place where you declare it should be obvious to you, as it'll expose the visibility (scope) of the variable to everywhere in your program that needs to see it.

I recommend using a `char *` variable for this. `realloc` doesn't like uninitialised values, so I also highly recommend initialising it to `NULL`.

```
char *last_timestamp_str = NULL;
```

Be careful when you use this variable in your logic; in parts of your program it'll adopt a non-`NULL` value, but you need to realise that other parts of your program might see a `NULL` value before-hand. I shouldn't need to explain that dereferencing a null pointer is bad news.

To give `last_timestamp_str` a non-`NULL` value solving your problem, you can first call `realloc` with the return value of `snprintf` (which will be the length of our total string) to allocate an array for our string, and then call `sprintf` to copy the string into the array.

For example...

```
void *temp = realloc(last_timestamp_str, snprintf(NULL, 0, "Timestamp, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s ", 
                                         channels[1].title, 
                                         channels[2].title, 
                                         channels[3].title, 
                                         channels[4].title, 
                                         channels[5].title, 
                                         channels[6].title, 
                                         channels[7].title) + 1);
if (temp == NULL) {
    /* XXX: Handle allocation error */
    free(last_timestamp_str);
    exit(0);
}
last_timestamp_str = temp;
sprintf(last_timestamp_str, "Timestamp, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s ", 
                            channels[1].title, 
                            channels[2].title, 
                            channels[3].title, 
                            channels[4].title, 
                            channels[5].title, 
                            channels[6].title, 
                            channels[7].title);
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I used it and ran printf to see if last_timestamp_str was printing as it should but I got very strange symbols that printed instead :( Do you know what that could mean?

Comment: Nerermind. I have figured it out haha. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is the [sprintf() function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) (and its family) that prints into a buffer.